# Is there any articles related to Windows account, user token, security and so on?

Tags: windows

guys~~ I am trying to get a through understanding about Windows's management mechanism about account, users, user token, especially *impersonation* and so on. I know these words putting together forms a mess, no strange, cause i am just starting on this topic.. Many thanks.

Scenario: I am trying to write a small program to test impersonation. I want to start a new process with another domain account through impersonation. But I have read that impersonation is basically for thread, could it be possible for process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Russinovich has a wealth of Windows internals information. He works at Microsoft now... see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).

The sysinternals suite (made by him) has utilities (free) for checking things like tokens and user privileges and such too.